# find location from base address

Tags: arrays, pseudo-element, memory-address

So my computer science professor decided to ask us a question but gave no instruction on how to find the answer. The question is as follow:

Compute the location of the following elements, where the base address is FFFFFBACD:
A[4][6], A[5][5], A[2][7] 
The array is declared as int [][]= new int [8][10]

He isn't asking us to program anything but just find the location. The issue I have is that the base address looks off and I have no idea how to do the calculation to find the answer. Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Are you sure this is Java-related?

Comment: a) look up the memory size of an int. b) use that size to calculate offsets from the base of the array c) add those offsets to your ...BACD base. d) ??? e) profit

Comment: we are in the the last part of learning java, so I assumed it was related.

Comment: Java doesn't have memory addresses like C. Is this possibly just some exercise designed to teach you how to compute a multidimensional array index...? Please clarify.

Comment: The syntax looks like Java, but the question cannot be answered for Java.  Apart from the whole "Java doesn't have pointers" thing, the elements of a Java multi-dimensional array are not necessarily laid out contiguously in memory, so the "base address" and indices are not sufficient to determine their addresses.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your integers are 4 bytes each, then element [0][0] is at address `FFFFFBACD`.

The next element is [0][1] in a distance of 4 bytes, meaning: `FFFFFBAD1`.

Overall in each "row" you have 10 elements, thus 40 bytes. Therefore the address for [1][0] is FFFFFBACD + 40 bytes = `FFFFFBAF5`

Therefore, [4][6] will be 40*4 + 5*4 bytes from the start address: `FFFFFBB85`.

(note that here the number of rows is 4 and multiplies 40 bytes per row and the number of elements in the fifth row is 6 and each is 4 bytes long - these are different reasons for multiplying by 4).

Using this logic, try and find the other addresses. It shouldn't be that hard.

Comment: This is correct for C, and I guess for C++.  It is most likely the response the instructor expects.  Not all languages lay out arrays the same way, however.